# Clicking noise in my car when I accelerate over 20ks

Tags: electrical

I have a 1998 Mazda Sentia. Everytime I accelerate over 20ks a clicking kind of sound happens inside the car (Sounds like continuous unlocking and locking of the doors). You can hear it more in the driver's side and also the behind the passenger side. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this? Also, How can I fix this problem? Any advice or help is very much appreciated.

Comment: it could be an exhaust gas leak , Can you hear it more loudly under the car than near the engine ?

Comment: Just to be sure by accelerating  you mean you rev up the engine while the car is not moving

Comment: Is your car meant to lock the doors once you start moving?

Comment: If you mean moving then it is one of the doors not locking and the car keeps trying to lock it repeatedly with no success

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: While the car is moving. As soon as you get to 20ks it starts the clicking noise but driving under 20ks there's no noise. I'm not to sure if the doors are supposed to lock automatically, but only the passenger door locks as soon as you turn the key, all the other doors stay unlocked whilst driving.

Answer (score 1):

I would be highly suspicious of the front axle CV joints. As they wear they tend to make a clicking sound. It will typically get worse under heavy acceleration or when making tight turns typical of parking lot maneuvers. Rebuilt axles are usually readily available from your local parts supplier. A rebuilt axle is typically less expensive than buying two new CV joints and rebuilding it yourself.   Replacing the axles is not beyond the scope of a driveway repair. In most cases the only specialty tool required is a socket large enough to remove the axle nut and a torque wrench to reinstall the new nut during reassemble.